# Calculating variance of MC estimator of an integral

Tags: variance, simulation, monte-carlo, integral, numerical-integration

Let 
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}, \quad I = \int \limits_0^1 f(x) dx.
$$

We consider the following estimator of I:
$$
\hat{I}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^n f(X_i),
$$
where $X_1, X_2, ...$ are iid $U(0,1)$.

The task is to calculate $Var(\hat{I}_n)$.

My approach:
$$
Var(f(X_1)) = E[f(X_1)]^2 - (Ef(X_1))^2 = \int_0^1 1 - x^2 dx - \Big{(}  \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 - x^2} dx \Big{)}^2 = \frac{2}{3} - \Big{(}\frac{\pi}{4}\Big{)}^2
$$
$$
Var(\hat{I}_n) = Var\Big{(}  \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^n f(X_i) \Big{)} = \frac{1}{n^2} Var\Big{(}\sum \limits_{i=1}^n f(X_i) \Big{)} = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum \limits_{i=1}^n Var(f(X_i)) = \frac{1}{n^2} n \Big{(}\frac{2}{3} - \Big{(}\frac{\pi}{4}\Big{)}^2 \Big{)}
$$

Is that correct?

My other question is how to estimate $Var(\hat{I}_n)$ using  simulation?

```
n <- 100000
U <- runif(n)
X <- sqrt(1-U^2)
I <- mean(X)
```

Here `I` is the estimator of the itegral and `var(X)` gives me approximately $\frac{2}{3} - \Big{(}\frac{\pi}{4}\Big{)}^2$

But when I try to estimate $Var(I_n)$

```
w <-c ()
for(i in 1:1000){
  U <- runif(n)
  X <- sqrt(1-U^2)
  I <- mean(X)
  w <- c(w,I)
}
```

Here, `var(w)` is approximately 5.01359e-07. If I use the formula devired above $Var(\hat{I}_n) = \frac{1}{n} \Big{(}\frac{2}{3} - \Big{(}\frac{\pi}{4}\Big{)}^2 \Big{)} \approx 4.981639e-05$

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations seem correct. Since $n$ is large, and iterate only 1000 times in the outer loop, the variance you get is fluctuating a lot around small numbers. Try the following, where the variance is better noticeable:

```
n <- 10
w <-c ()
for(i in 1:50000){
  U <- runif(n)
  X <- sqrt(1-U^2)
  I <- mean(X)
  w <- c(w,I)
}
var(w)
(2/3 - (pi/4)^2)/n
```

Comment: I see :) great :D Thank you very much!

Comment: It's also quite interesting that in order to calculate the variance of your estimator, we actually use the result of the integral. Then, what was the point in estimating it :)

Comment: That's true :D I did not notice that! The sad answer is: in order to prepare to the exam :)